# How to get current recylcerview item position when you have horizontal layout manager attached in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a recyclerview so on each horizontal scroll one item is swapped, meanwhile I have a toolbar-like header upwards which only consists of textviews, I want that textviews to change according to recyclerview's current item's position, how do I get that position? note that I can't do it directly in an adapter since Recyclerview usually loads 4-5 items and position won't retrieve when you scroll backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually did some research, wasn't needed to post the question probably.

So what I basically did is that I used OnScrollListener of recyclerview, and overrode OnScrollStateChanged.
Code looks like this

```
public class OnScrollListenerWallet : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
    {
        public override void OnScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
        {
            base.OnScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            int pos = 0;
            if (newState == RecyclerView.ScrollStateIdle)
            {
                pos = ln.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                myPassedTextView.Text = myCollection[pos].Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in activity you just :

```
recyclerView.AddOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListenerWallet(myPassedTextView,myLayoutManager,myCollection));
```

`